# gsm modem in python

Tags: python, gsm

I want make relation with gsm modem.
my first goal and main one is sending and receiving sms.
*then I want go front.for example for mms sending and ...*
I want to do it on a linux server.
please introduce me a suitable modula with it's tutorial or documentation.
thanks if guide me.

Answer (score 1):

You need gammu http://wammu.eu/

Answer (score 0):

I agree with *funfullson*, but I want to add that you can use the API of Gammu-smsd to Python language (python-gammu API). Also, I advise you to link your gammu-smsd to the control management interface [Kalkun is the must have tool to organize contacts, schedule/automate SMS and with event calendar (soon :-) it will be unstoppable."](http://kalkun.sourceforge.net/)

which has a lot of plugins, from forward incoming messages to your e-mail address and publication in the popular social networks to execution predefined commands and scripts.